# Return JSON Using Map

Tags: json, rest, hashmap

I have a method, which changes the status from 'Active' to 'InActive' and vice

versa, of a record, by fetching it's id.

Now, I want to **convert** it to return a ResponseEntity object, inside which, I have a map stored

When I test my method, I get a **400: Bad Request**

////////////////////////**Old Method**////////////////

```
@RequestMapping("toggleStatus")
    public @ResponseBody void toggleStatus(@RequestParam("resourceId") Long resourceId ){
        ResourceElementMaster resourceElementMaster = resourceElementService.findById(resourceId);
        if(resourceElementMaster.getIsActive() == true) {
            resourceElementMaster.setIsActive(false);
        } else {
            resourceElementMaster.setIsActive(true);
        }
        resourceElementService.update(resourceElementMaster);
    }
```

//////////////////////**New Method**/////////////////////////////

```
@RequestMapping(value="toggleStatus",method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> toggleStatus(@RequestBody Long resourceId ){
        Map<String, Object> mapToggle=new HashMap<String, Object>();
        ResourceElementMaster resourceElementMaster = resourceElementService.findById(resourceId);
        if(resourceElementMaster.getIsActive() == true) {
            resourceElementMaster.setIsActive(false);
        } else {
            resourceElementMaster.setIsActive(true);
        }
        mapToggle.put("Update",resourceElementService.update(resourceElementMaster));
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(mapToggle, HttpStatus.OK) ;
    }
```

How do I solve this??

Comment: The JSON which I pass, to test this method, is : {
"resourceId": 57,
"isActive":true
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pass a json, you only need to pass the resourceId, which you are accepting as a parameter in your method toggleStatus.

Also, use @RequestParam, instead of @RequestBody :

```
@RequestMapping(value="toggleStatus",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> toggleStatus(@RequestParam(value = "resourceId") Long resourceId ){
    Map<String, Object> mapToggle=new HashMap<String, Object>();
    ResourceElementMaster resourceElementMaster = resourceElementService.findById(resourceId);
    if(resourceElementMaster.getIsActive() == true) {
        resourceElementMaster.setIsActive(false);
    } else {
        resourceElementMaster.setIsActive(true);
    }
    mapToggle.put("Update",resourceElementService.update(resourceElementMaster));
    return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(mapToggle, HttpStatus.OK) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You problem is, you are trying to pass an `json` to your `/toggleStatus` Method. But your `@Controller` accepts only a `resourceId`of type `Long`.

So your response via Postman should be something like this:

PUT `http://localhost:8080/toggleStatus?resouceId=42`

also, there is no need for `RequestEntity` in your case. Modify your `@controller` like this:

```
@ResponseBody 
@RequestMapping(value = "toggleStatus", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public Object toggleStatus(@RequestParam Long resourceId ){
    Map<String, Object> mapToggle = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    ResourceElementMaster resourceElementMaster = resourceElementService.findById(resourceId);
    resourceElementMaster.setIsActive(!resourceElementMaster.getIsActive());
    mapToggle.put("Update", resourceElementService.update(resourceElementMaster));
    return mapToggle;
}
```

Comment: Same : 400 Bad Request.

Comment: How do I test it?? I passed the following JSON in Postman : {
"resourceId": 57,
"version":1,
"name":"Allegation1",
"Active":true
}

Comment: Why you are passing a `json`? Your Controller accepts only a `resourceId`.